# How to add Component on each side using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to have Component `Header` on each side and in React you can simply achieve this with passing Component before `<Switch>` from `react-router-dom` and how can be done this with Next.js?

I was trying to follow this tutorial but no results: https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/

I was trying also to implement that advancted stuff from Next.js documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

**pages/index.js**

```
const Home = ({ products }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(products);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Advantages></Advantages>
      <Recommend products={products}></Recommend>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to add one **Header** component that should be visible on each side in my application. Can I do this with Next.js??

Comment: Share what you have in your custom app, as in your _app.js

Comment: I didn't change that, I let that as in official Next documentation and don't know how to use this _app

Comment: Please share the exact code you have for that _app.js file even if it’s unchanged. Also share the code for any imported components you use in that _app.js . /pages/app.js would be the perfect place to add components that you want to render on every page/route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guest you want a layout all of your page? If so, [with-app-layout](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-app-layout) which is a official example you can reference.